# Considering engagement

Tags: kinect, usability, kinect-sdk

I've just read the Kinect SDK 1.7 Human Interface Guidelines and was very impressed by the fact that they consider the user engagement (page 86).

I was wonderin how we're supposed to implement this. I could not find anything in the SDK Documentation which confused me. Are we supposed to do all this by hand?

Since 1.7 is pretty new I don't expect many other to have much experience with this but maybe someone stumbled upon something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 93 of the [Kinect for Windows Human Interface Guidelines](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/7/B070724E-52B4-4B1A-BD1B-05CC28D07899/Human_Interface_Guidelines_v1.7.0.pdf) describes an example of implementing an engagement philosophy.  The example applications it is referring to is "Control Basics-WPF" and "Interaction Gallery-WPF" (SDK 1.7); or the older "[Basic Interactions](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/)" example (SDK 1.6).  You can run the examples to see them in action and examine the code to see how it is implemented.

> Are we supposed to do all this by hand?

Microsoft provides then `EngagementStateManager` in `Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Utilities`, which is demonstrated in the "Interaction Gallery-WPF" example.  It will provide you with the engagement logic defined by Microsoft.  If you wish to have a different engagement model, you need to write your own.